# .NET Core Docker Poor Performance

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

We have an application that has been containerized on a Ubuntu 18.04 host. This is a dedicated server, with 12 physical cores, and currently nothing other than the OS running.

We have been doing some performance diagnostics and realised that for some reason it was running slower than we expected. To confirm this we wrote a very simple bit of code and compared the time taken to run in Visual Studio debugger vs in the container. Please see code below:

```
           var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
           stopWatch.Start();
           Dictionary<Guid, string> Items = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
           for(int x = 0; x<= 1000000; x++)
           {
               if(Items.ContainsKey(Guid.NewGuid()))
               Items.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
           }

           stopWatch.Stop();

           Console.WriteLine("Speed [{0}]", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The results:

Visual Studio Debugger (6 core machine): 224ms
Docker Container (12 core machine): 1309ms

This is clearly not right and has lead us to come to a few conclusions.

1) The StopWatch is not accurate on the docker container
2) The performance is simply not as good

One other strange thing we noticed was this. When originally testing this we were recording performance in ticks. Our understanding is that there are 10,000 ticks in a MS. On this container it is in fact 1,000,000 in a MS. Is this to be expected?

Comment: you're doing a single-threaded benchmark. so it doesn't matter if you have 6 cores, 12, 1 or 10000 - maybe compare your results based on the single-thread-performance of the CPUs in question. also, to specifically check performance inside docker, you should test on the _same hardware_.

Comment: Also have you checked, maybe some resource limitations are applied either to docker itself or to  the container?

Comment: this is a single core test..... so its not using more than 1, so then the speed would be made by how high the clock is...2.4 ghz vs 4 ghz

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/ Learn how to properly test performance please.

Comment: seems like a really silly test ;-)... but yeah biggest problem is this is just using 1 core.... aka 1 core machine at 2 ghz will always beat a 16 core machine at 1.5ghz each when only 1 core is used.... but if you used all the core well then it will basically be 16x faster. Somethings are hard to design with parallelism in mind. its probably better to post the code in question.... rather than the test you setup.

Comment: You are correct about it being a single-threaded test, should have realized that! It's not possible to test on the same hardware, CPU speeds are similar 2.4Ghz on server vs 2.67Ghz on Development machine, so would not explain the factor of 5 difference. Will re-test using Benchmark.NET and report back

Comment: Also i appreciate it is a very basic test, but i wanted to test something as simple as possible to try and find differences. This problem was discovered by the fact that looking up an entry from a local Redis server was for some reason slower than on the development machine over a VPN!

Comment: Now put this test in a function and run that function 50 times. Take the best time. I bet it'll be lower, perhaps much lower. You're benchmarking just-in-time compiler performance and other startup overheads.

Comment: tried running it 50 times... slight improvement 946ms, so now just under a factor of 4 out. May try installing docker on dev machine and see what happens there.